# Non generation of the dll file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

Hello I did a new project (console application), it's supposed to have a dll file as an output but it seems that it's not existing in the project folder after the build. Is that normal?
[image]

Comment: An application builds an executable program (exe), not a library (dll). You probably want to create a class library project instead.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I put it as a library for the purpose of using it later in an application.

Comment: @MelMed Makes no difference what you are going to use it for *later*. If you want to build a DLL you need to create a DLL project not an app project.

Comment: @john I have created two projects ( DLL and APP) in one solution.

Comment: @MelMed, looks like you need a project reference in your application project that points to your library project, then.

Comment: @MelMed OK fair enough, that wasn't clear before. You should be able to find the DLL then, do you get any build errors?

Comment: I did the reference. And before, I was having some errors. Now the link is done, and the rebuild is successful. But as soon as I play the app, it says as a system error, the program can t start because test.dll (coming from the dll project test) is missing from your computer. Try installing the program to fix this problem.

Comment: Does the dll exist in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: @drescherjm the DLL project is in a separate folder, but is included in the project solution.

Comment: @drescherjm but what is weird for me is the missing dll file that i am not finding

Comment: @MelMed Applications can't just pick up DLLs from  any old place on your hard drive. The DLL must either be in a location mentioned on your PATH variable, or they must be in the current working directory.

Comment: Make a custom build step to copy the dll to the folder containing the executable. Or set the default path of the application to the folder the dll is in.

Comment: @MelMed If you DLL is really missing then you must have a build error when you build the DLL project. To answer your question it's not normal for it to be missing.

Comment: for sure it's not on my current working directory. I have dug too much in the working directory and I am not seriously finding it.

Comment: When searching for it (f3), I am finding it in another directory ( another previous solution)!!!

Comment: Well your project settings are whacked. I would recreate the projects from scratch. Who knows what other problems there are.

Comment: And how to include then that .dll file into my project or even copy it to avoid the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New conception / creation / organization of my code would be the solution for that.